# what's the difference between those two?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  var test = function(x) {
         return x + 2;
    };
```

and I can use test(3)

but when I use

```
  var test = (function(x) {
         return x + 2;
    })();
```

I cannot use test(3)

why?

Comment: because in the second example you are defining test as the return value, not the function

Comment: Because () executes function in runtime immediately, so test gets the result of function with no arguments (NaN). Then you are trying to run NaN as a function

Comment: You could do `var test = (function(x) { return x + 2; })(3);`, but that defeats the point of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet is an example of an IIFE - [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

The result of the expression inside the first set of parens defines a function that takes one parameter (named `x`). The second set of parens immediately invokes it, returning the result. Since you passed no arguments when invoking it, `x` is `undefined` so it evaluates the expression `undefined + 2` and returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you is defining a function, so you can do `test(3)`

In the second case you are [executing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) a function, so, probably, you are getting `NaN` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you're taking advantage of JavaScript closures. Closures allow you to control scoping and namespacing, and to declare private methods and variables.

Consider the following:

```
var test = (function() {
 var privateVar1;
 var privateVar2;

 function privateFunction() {
 }

 return {
    publicFunction1: function() {
    },
    publicFunction2: function() {
    }
 };
})();
```

`test` is now equal to the following:

`{ publicFunction1: function() {}, publicFunction2: function() {} }`

The function is immediately invoked after being declared, at which point `x` does not have a value. Initialize `x` before the function declaration (outside of its scope) to fix the problem you're experience:

```
var x = 10;
var test = (function(x) {
         return x + 2;
    })();
```